# Show that the sequence is exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, exact-sequence

We have that $R$ is a commutative ring.

Suppose that $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\overset{f}{\rightarrow} C\rightarrow 0$ and $0\rightarrow C\overset{g}\rightarrow D\rightarrow E\rightarrow 0$ are exact sequences.

> I want to show that $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\overset{gf}{\rightarrow} D\rightarrow E\rightarrow 0$ is also exact.

Could you give me some hints?

---

Let $\dots\rightarrow A_{i-2}\overset{f_{i-2}}{\rightarrow}A_{i-1}\overset{f_{i-1}}{\rightarrow}A_i\overset{f_i}{\rightarrow}A_{i+1}\rightarrow\cdots$ be a sequence of $R$-modules and $R$-homomorphisms.

It is exact at $A_i$ iff $\ker f_i=\text{Im}f_{i-1}$.

It is exact iff it is exact at each $A_i$.

---

> What does $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\overset{f}{\rightarrow} C\rightarrow 0$ mean? Maybe $0\overset{f}{\rightarrow} A\overset{f}{\rightarrow} B\overset{f}{\rightarrow} C\overset{f}{\rightarrow}0$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

We have that each exact sequence can be arised by short exact sequences as above, right?

But how could we prove this? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: the chain is identical up to the first 3. we can compose fictions f,g at C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want the first term in your exact sequence to be a $0$ (zero )too, not an $O$.
$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\overset{f}{\rightarrow} C\rightarrow 0$$
Just means that we don't bother to give a name to the morphism $A\to B$. In particular it does not mean
$$0\overset{f}{\rightarrow} A\overset{f}{\rightarrow} B\overset{f}{\rightarrow} C\overset{f}{\rightarrow}0$$
Which doesn't even make sense unless $A=B=C=0$.

For the main question, just note that we a map
$$f:B\to C$$
$$g:C\to D$$
Which we can compose to get
$$g\circ f:B\to D$$
You are asked to show that this map makes the longer sequence
$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\overset{g\circ f}{\rightarrow} D\rightarrow E\rightarrow 0$$
exact

---

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with your new question. Every long exact sequence can be 'weaved together' from short exact sequences as follows:
[image: wiki image]

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to define the $C_i$ in terms of the $A_i$ and maps between them. Let me know if this answers your question or if you are looking for something else.

---

I'll give some more information:

If we are given any exact sequence $S$:
$$\dots\to A_{n-1}\stackrel{f_{n-1}}{\to}A_{n}\stackrel{f_{n}}{\to}A_{n+1}\stackrel{f_{n+1}}{\to}\dots $$
Then we can construct a sequence of short exact sequences $S_n$ as follows:
The middle term of $S_n$ will be $A_n$. Given the exact sequence $S$, what is a natural object + map that injects into $A_n$? The answer is $\ker f_n$ with the inclusion. What is a natural object and map that $A_n$ surjects into? The answer is $\text{image}(f_n)$ with the map $f_n$. So we construct a new short exact sequence:
$$0\to \ker f_n\stackrel{i}{\to} A_n\stackrel{f_n}{\to}\text{image}f_n\to 0$$
The question is, is this sequence indeed exact? The only non trivial part is checking whether $\text{image}i=\ker f_n$. But this is true by definition, since $i$ is just the inclusion of $\ker f_n$ into $A_n$.

Now we note that if we consider $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$ we have
$$0\to \ker f_n\stackrel{i}{\to} A_n\stackrel{f_n}{\to}\text{image}f_n\to 0$$
$$0\to \ker f_{n+1}\stackrel{i}{\to} A_{n+1}\stackrel{f_{n+1}}{\to}\text{image}f_{n+1}\to 0$$
But since the sequence $S$ is exact by assumption, $\text{image}f_n=\ker f_{n+1}$. Hence we are in the situation of your original question, and we find that we can combine $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$ into a longer exact sequence by composing (as in your original question):
$$0\to \ker f_n\stackrel{i}{\to} A_n\stackrel{i\circ f_n}{\to}A_{n+1}\stackrel{f_{n+1}}{\to}\text{image}f_{n+1}\to 0$$
Note that $i\circ f_n=f_n$, hence we can rewrite the above simply as
$$0\to \ker f_n\stackrel{i}{\to} A_n\stackrel{f_n}{\to}A_{n+1}\stackrel{f_{n+1}}{\to}\text{image}f_{n+1}\to 0$$
And we can keep repeating this procedure; this longer sequence can be combined with $S_{n+2}$ and $S_{n-1}$.

In this way every exact sequence arises as a composition of short exact sequences.

Comment: Ah ok... So, to show that the sequence $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\overset{g\circ f}{\rightarrow} D\rightarrow E\rightarrow 0$ is exact, do we have to show that it is exact at $B$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Just use the definition. You have to show injectivity of $A\to B$, but this is given by the original sequence. Then you have to show $$\text{image}(A\to B)=\text{ker}(g\circ f)$$ and $$\text{image}(g\circ f)=\text{ker}(D\to E)$$. Then surjectivity of $D\to E$ is again just given by the original sequence. To show the two non-obvious ones, you will have to use that $f:B\to C$ is surjective, and $g:C\to D$ is injective, as is given by the original sequences.

Comment: I got stuck right now... Why do we have to show that $A\to B$ is injective and that $D\to E$ is surjective?

Comment: What does the $$0\to A\to B$$ part of the sequence mean? Just apply the definition: $\text{image}(0\to A)=\text{ker}(A\to B)$. What is $\text{image}(0\to A)$? The image of a morphism from the trivial ring is just $\{0_A\}\subset A$. I.e. we have to show $$\text{image}(0\to A)=\{0_A\}=\text{ker}(A\to B)$$ but this means exactly that $A\to B$ is injective.

Comment: Ah ok... I got it!! Thank you very much!! :-) $$$$ How could we show that each exact sequence can be implied by a short exact sequence? @user2520938

Comment: Could we maybe prove that it holds for each exact sequence using induction?

Comment: @MaryStar see my edit.

Comment: So, is $C_i$ either $\ker f_i$ or $\text{im} f_{i+1}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar If the originial sequence is $$\dots\to A_{n-1}\stackrel{f_{n-1}}{\to}A_{n}\stackrel{f_{n}}{\to}A_{n+1}\stackrel{f_{n+1}}{\to}\dots$$ then  $C_i$ is either $\ker f_{i}$ or $\text{im}f_{i-1}$, and these are equal since the sequence is exact.

Comment: Ah ok... And which is the function $h:C_i\rightarrow A_i$ ? Is it a composition of the functions $f_i$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar no, as I included in my last edit, $C_i\to A_i$ is the inclusion of the kernel of $f_i$ into $A_i$, and $A_i\to C_{i+1}$ is $f_i$ with its range restricted to $C_{i+1}=\text{image} f_i$

Comment: I read it again, since I got stuck at some parts... We consider an exact sequence $\dots\to A_{n-1}\stackrel{f_{n-1}}{\to}A_{n}\stackrel{f_{n}}{\to}A_{n+1}\stackrel{f_{n+1}}{\to}\dots$ and we want to create two short exact sequences to show that their composition gives us the original sequence, right? To construct these short sequences we consider a new mapping $i:\ker f_n\rightarrow A_n$, or not? I haven't really understood why $\text{im} i=\ker f_n$. Could you explain it further to me?

Answer (score 1):

I name the injective and surjective homomorphisms as $$0\rightarrow  A\overset{j}\rightarrow B\overset{f}{\rightarrow} C\rightarrow 0$$ and $$0\rightarrow C\overset{g}\rightarrow D\overset{p}\rightarrow E\rightarrow 0.$$

> Note that by exactness of 1st sequence, $\operatorname {ker} j=\operatorname {im} (0\to A)=0,$ so that $j$ is injective. By exactness of 2nd sequence, $\operatorname {im} p=\operatorname {ker} (E\to 0)=E,$ so that $p$ is surjective.

To show that 
$0\rightarrow A\overset{j}\rightarrow B\overset{gf}{\rightarrow} D\overset{p}\rightarrow E\rightarrow 0$  is exact one need to see $j$ is injective and $p$ is surjective (which inherites from first and second exact sequences), and
1. $\operatorname {ker}  gf =\operatorname{im} j$
2. $\operatorname{im} gf =\operatorname{ker} p$

1. $\operatorname {ker}  gf \overset{def.}= \{x\in B| gf(x)=0\}\overset{g:inj.}=\{x\in B| f(x)=0\}=\operatorname{ker} f = \operatorname{im} j$
2. $\operatorname{im} gf \overset{f:surj.}= \operatorname{im} g =\operatorname{ker} p$

   ---

The long exact sequence $\dots\rightarrow A_{i-2}\overset{f_{i-2}}{\rightarrow}A_{i-1}\overset{f_{i-1}}{\rightarrow}A_i\overset{f_i}{\rightarrow}A_{i+1}\rightarrow\cdots$ made by the exact sequences like:

$\dots\rightarrow A_{i-2}\overset{f_{i-2}}{\rightarrow}A_{i-1}\overset{p}{\rightarrow}im f_{i-1}\to 0$ 
and
$0\to im f_{i-1}\overset{j}{\rightarrow}A_i\overset{f_i}{\rightarrow}A_{i+1}\rightarrow\cdots$

Comment: To show that a long exact sequence is made by the exact sequences as you mentioned, we use the first part of my question, i.e., when two sequences are exact then the composition is also exact, or not?

Comment: yes, we use the first part of the question to compose two exact sequences and get new one

Comment: Ah ok... And have we proved in that way that **each** sequence can be made by short exact sequences?

Comment: yes **each exact** sequence. (but not necessarily with **finite** short exact sequences)

Comment: Can short exact sequences be infinite?

Comment: Could we maybe prove that it holds for each exact sequence using induction?